# How to show lineage from Power BI report in Azure Purview to Azure SQL Database?

Tags: azure-purview

I'm just finished with setting up our Purview account. After a few scans, and correcting some privileges issues I can get details from the storage account, Azure SQL Database (main source for Power BI datasets), and Power BI datasets / reports.

[image: Microsoft Azure Purview]

The main thing that has my interest is the lineage from Power BI Datasets to the source. Most reports will have one Azure SQL Database as a source. I want to check with tables are used. However, it seems that this information is not available.

In [this post by Microsoft](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/microsoft-power-bi-and-azure-purview-work-better-together-is-now-in-ga/), there is an image that shows the kind of lineage that I'm looking for.

[image: Power BI lineage to Azure SQL Database]

How can I achieve this insight with Azure Purview?

Comment: Have you found the answer or work around?

Comment: Well, to be honest, I did not find a workaround but asked an intern to download all Power BI reports and manually check what the datasources were. Not the most elegant solution but it did the trick ;-)

I think if the Power BI reports are hosted in a premium workspace the datalineage works fine.

Comment: Any luck as of today?